# how to rearrange a division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLHk7WkgdKw

At 3:55 we have $\tan 34.4^\circ=9.16/b$, and the kind sir says that to calculate $b$ he needs to change the equation to $b = 9.16/\tan 34.4^\circ$.

I've seen this trick used alot before, but I never seem to grasp it. What is the logic behind him changing the order? How do I know what to divide or multiply?

Does the trick have a name? I've tried to search for "rearranging formula" like it said in the video, but it  didnt get me far.

I hope I used the right tag.

Thanks!

Comment: $$\rm x=\frac{y}{z}\iff xz=y\iff z=\frac{y}{x} $$

Comment: @anon I understand thats the formula but I don't understand the logic behind it

Comment: @anon I understand it now, lol, thanks.

Comment: To go from $x=\frac{y}{z}$ to $xz=y$, we multiply by $z$. If we wanted to do that in reverse, we would have dividied $xz=y$ by $z$ to obtain $x=\frac{y}{z}$. What we can do is divide $xz=y$ by $x$ to obtain $z=\frac{y}{x}$ instead.

Comment: What do I do when a comment answers my question? Do I leave this open?

Comment: If you like the math in my comments better than the current answer, I recommend putting it into your own words in an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anon's comment helped me out perfectly.

"To go from x=yz to xz=y, we multiply by z. If we wanted to do that in reverse, we would have dividied xz=y by z to obtain x=yz. What we can do is divide xz=y by x to obtain z=yx instead."

Answer (score 2):

What he's done is multiply both sides of the equation by $$\frac b{\tan{34.4^\circ}},$$ which is legal because $\tan{34.4^\circ} \neq 0$.